# Fetch word range of a sentence from character range in a paragraph

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of words that is

```
Birds are a group of endothermic vertebrates, characterised by feathers Birds are also known as Aves They have toothless beaked jaws They have a high metabolic rate Birds are also known as Aves
```

What I need to do is find multiple occurrences of the words 'Birds are also known as Aves'. So I have written a regex to match the character index of 'Birds are also known as Aves' in this paragraph. Here I get two matches:

The span here represents character range.

```
   <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(72, 100), match='Birds are also known as Aves'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(165, 193), match='Birds are also known as Aves'>
```

But I need to know the word range instead of the character range. As in the word range (10,16) in the first match and (27,33) in the second match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`regex` do not support that but you could calculate it on the fly like so:

```
import re
s = 'Birds are a group of endothermic vertebrates, characterised by feathers Birds are also known as Aves They have toothless beaked jaws They have a high metabolic rate Birds are also known as Aves'

pat = 'Birds are also known as Aves'
pat_len = len(pat.split())
for x in re.finditer(pat, s):
    start = len(s[:x.start()].split())
    end = start + pat_len
    print(start, end)
```

Answer (score 0):

"What I need to do is find the occurrence " -> assuming there is one occurence only:

```
s = ("Birds are a group of endothermic vertebrates, characterised by feathers "
    "Birds are also known as Aves They have toothless beaked jaws They have a high "
     "metabolic rate Birds are also known as Aves")
sub = "Birds are also known as Aves"
len_sub = len(sub.split())
len_left = len(s.split(sub)[0].split())
print(len_left, len_left+len_sub)
```